# Question about P value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value, clinical-trials

If it is said that a trial prespecified one-sided overall type one error of 2.5%, and the trial was designed to assess superiority, so one sided tests were specified for the alternative hypothesis, critical regions, and P values. However, two-sided tests are reported. For example: two-sided P-value = 0.006 and another two-sided P-value < 0.001. How do I interpret the significance of the P-values? According to 0.025 or 0.05?

Comment: You have stumbled into yet another problem with the classifical (frequentist) school of statistics.  A lot of mumbo-jumbo had to be created with regard to one-tailed vs. two-tailed tests.  In the Bayesian world one just computes directional quantities, e.g., probability of a positive effect of a treatment on an outcome.  The study to which you refer should have been consistent in reporting one-tailed p-values as the statistical plan said were going to be used.

Comment: I would pay little attention to reports of a trial based on analyses that violate the original protocol for analysis. About the same attention a casino operator would give to someone who bets on black at roulette, loses, and then wants some credit for 'really intending to bet on red all the time'.// What prospects do we have here? A promising drug for raising high BP?, A treatment to help high BMI people gain weight? A pill to make headaches last longer?